# Relations between dynamo db tables

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I have two tables named Country and State.
How to get country information through mapping relation.
Here is my code:

### tables:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "cd_country2")
public class Country implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5698425418072128936L;

    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    @DynamoDBHashKey
    private String countryId;

    private String countryCode;
    private String countryName;
    private Long isActive;
}
```

---

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "cd_state2")
public class State implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7289597915417184960L;

    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    @DynamoDBHashKey
    private String stateId;

    @DynamoDBRangeKey
    private String countryId;

    private String stateCode;

    private String stateName;

    private Long isActive;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your application, can one state be in multiple countries? If not then there is no need to make the countryId a rangeKey. Something like this should work:

```
@DynamoDBHashKey
private String stateId;

// attributes    
private String countryId;

private String stateCode;

private String stateName;

private Long isActive;
```

Given a stateId, you can find the countryId it belongs to from your "cd_state2" table.

On the other hand, I would recommend using the schema like this:

```
HashKey: countryId
RangeKey: stateId
Attributes: stateCode, stateName, isActive
```

Then build a GSI on top of this table:

```
HashKey: stateId
```

So assuming the stateId is unique across country, given a State you can find its Country by doing a GET on the GSI table. Also, given a countryId, you can find all the states in it by query the base table.